# How to create VPN (pptp) connection using nmcli in Linux

Tags: linux, vpn

Also,

I created vpn settings file (valid) manually and copied the file to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` folder and restarted the `network-manager` but the connection is not showing up when i do `nmcli con list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the reason why the not showing up when i do `nmcli con list` even after I copy the valid VPN settings file to file to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` folder....

> The configuration file must have -rw------ (600) permission, else it is not honored